TransferDatabase command not transferring data
I am trying to transfer the data and table structure from one database to another.
My database kept bloating, so I moved my linked tables to a separate database and I'm attempting to pull them into a local table in my current DB. When I use the TransferDatabase the DB acts like it's working but there is no data available.
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", "C:\Users\Desktop\External_DataSources.accdb", acTable, "tblLinked", "tblLocal", False

I do not receive any errors, the database just continues running the sequence as if it completed successfully - only no data is shown in the table.

Have you tried refreshing the link?

Is tblLinked in the separate DB also a linked table to a 3rd DB? I don't think you can do that, i.e. link over 2 "hops".

If you want to copy a table from another database into the current database, use acImport instead of acLink as the transfer type.

@Andre No it's only 1 tblLinked is a separate DB but no 3rd DB involved.

@Nathan_Sav yes, refreshed the link several times.

Use:
docmd.RunSQL ("select * into tblLocal from tblLinked")

For TransferDatabase: If you import a table from another Access database that's a linked table in that database, it will still be linked after you import it. That is, the link is imported, not the table itself.

Thank you! This worked much better than transferdatabase.
